# Groovy/Grails - Render cached JSON in JSON

Tags: json, grails

I want to render JSON containing a field that has cached JSON. How can I do this?

Example:

```
def cachedJSON = [cachedPropertyOne:'a', cachedPropertyTwo:'b'] as JSON
render([listEntryOne:'c', listEntryTwo:'d', cachedProperties: cachedJSON] as JSON)
```

The problem with the above code is that cachedProperties is escaped. For instance, `"` becomes `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, render as JSON does not like inline maps, so I always declare a variable and go like this:

```
def result = [:]
// assign values to result
render result as JSON
```

And it works as intended that way.

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code, cachedJSON is just a map so I'm assuming it's a standin for a string that is in json syntax.

For example, if `cachedJSON` is actually:

```
def cachedJSON = '{"cachedPropertyOne":"a","cachedPropertyTwo":"b"}'
```

Then you could use the [JSON](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/converters/JSON.html) class's `parse` method to convert it to a `JSONObject` which then can be placed back in the rendered map.

```
def cachedJSON = '{"cachedPropertyOne":"a","cachedPropertyTwo":"b"}'

render([
  listEntryOne:'c', 
  listEntryTwo:'d', 
  cachedProperties: JSON.parse(cachedJSON)
] as JSON)
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct - I edited my post. I'm hoping there's a more efficient way to go about it, though.